# compare 2 dataframe and add columns in order if not exist

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dataframes. 
df_A - This is a template dataframe which has a specific number of columns in order.

Eg: [emp_id, first_name, last_name, age, gender, dept]

df_B - This is a dataframe that may or may not contain all columns of df_A.

Eg: [emp_id, first_name, last_name, age,dept] = [ 001, john, mathew, 32, 047]

I want to compare df_B and df_A to create a new dataframe with 
[001, john, mathew, None, 047] with the column names same as that of df_A.

I am using python 3. I tried using

```
col_diff = df_A.columns.difference(df_B)
```

to get the column 'gender'. Then convert it to a list

```
col_diff.tolist()
```

and add it to df_B. But this column gets added to the end of df_B and I get

[001, john, mathew, 047, None]

But I want to preserve the column order same as that of df_A.

The output should be :
[001, john, mathew, None, 047]

Could you please help? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data:

```
c1 = ['emp_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'gender', 'dept']
df_A = pd.DataFrame(columns=c1)
print (df_A)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [emp_id, first_name, last_name, age, gender, dept]
Index: []

c2 = ['emp_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'dept']
df_B = pd.DataFrame([[ '001', 'john', 'mathew', 32, '047']], columns=c2)
print (df_B)
  emp_id first_name last_name  age dept
0    001       john    mathew   32  047
```

First get difference of columns by [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html), then [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) new columns created by `dict.fromkeys` and last for same ordering use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
col_diff = df_A.columns.difference(df_B.columns) 
print (col_diff)
Index(['gender'], dtype='object')

df = df_B.assign(**dict.fromkeys(col_diff, None)).reindex(columns=df_A.columns)
print (df)
  emp_id first_name last_name  age gender dept
0    001       john    mathew   32   None  047
```

Another solution:

```
df = df_B.reindex(columns=df_A.columns)
print (df)
  emp_id first_name last_name  age  gender dept
0    001       john    mathew   32     NaN  047
```